# Subplots with a line passing through them

Tags: r, r-plotly

I need to pass a through a bunch of violin plots in plotly. So I have come up with this code.

```
cd = data.frame(id = 1:100, norm = rnorm(100), poi = rpois(100, 1), exp 
= rexp(100,1))
cd = melt(cd, id= "id")
p1 = plot_ly(cd, x=~variable, y=~value, type = 'violin', box = 
list(visible =T), meanline = list(visible = T))%>%
layout(annotations = list(text = sprintf("Seeds=10, Coupons=5", 1:10), 
font = list(size=16), xanchor = "center", xref = "paper", yref = 
"paper", yanchor = "top", showarrow = F, y =1, x=0.5))

ad = data.frame(id = 1:100, norm = rnorm(100), poi = rpois(100, 1), exp 
= rexp(100,1))
ad = melt(ad, id= "id")
p2 = plot_ly(ad, x=~variable, y=~value, type = 'violin', box = 
list(visible =T), meanline = list(visible = T))%>%
layout(annotations = list(text = sprintf("Seeds=20, Coupons=5", 1:10), 
font = list(size=16), xanchor = "center", xref = "paper", yref = 
"paper", yanchor = "top", showarrow = F, y =1, x=0.5))
subplot(p1,p2, shareY = T)
```

and it gave me this plot
[image]

But what I'd love to see is a common line passing through 1.8 cutting all plots
[image]

also the 'trace 0' to be replaced with 'cd' and 'trace 1' to be replaced with 'ad'
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use add_lines in each plot to add a horizontal line, and by setting name = 'cd' or 'ad' you label the legends:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
cd = data.frame(id = 1:100, norm = rnorm(100), poi = rpois(100, 1), exp = rexp(100,1))
cd = melt(cd, id= "id")
p1 = plot_ly(cd, x=~variable, y=~value, type = 'violin',name = 'cd', box = 
list(visible =T), meanline = list(visible = T))%>% add_lines(x = ~variable, y =
rep(1.8,length(cd$id)),showlegend=FALSE)%>%
layout(annotations = list(text = sprintf("Seeds=10, Coupons=5", 1:10), 
font = list(size=16), xanchor = "center", xref = "paper", yref = 
"paper", yanchor = "top", showarrow = F, y =1, x=0.5))

ad = data.frame(id = 1:100, norm = rnorm(100), poi = rpois(100, 1), exp = 
rexp(100,1))
ad = melt(ad, id= "id")
p2 = plot_ly(ad, x=~variable, y=~value, type = 'violin',name = 'ad',box =
list(visible =T), meanline = list(visible = T))%>% add_lines(x = ~variable, y =
rep(1.8,length(ad$id)),showlegend=FALSE)%>%
layout(annotations = list(text = sprintf("Seeds=20, Coupons=5", 1:10), 
font = list(size=16), xanchor = "center", xref = "paper", yref = 
"paper", yanchor = "top", showarrow = F, y =1, x=0.5))

vline <- function(x = 0, color = "red") {
list(
type = "line", 
y0 = 0, 
y1 = 1, 
yref = "paper",
x0 = x, 
x1 = x, 
line = list(color = color)
  )
}

subplot(p1,p2, shareY = T)
```

Comment: Thanks, It does give the output, but is there a way to make that line continous?